# Qmail's preline command

Tags: spamassassin, email

Having trouble to use preline command with Qmail's mail filtering.

When i use next syntax in .qmail-default file:

```
| /var/qmail/bin/preline /usr/bin/maildrop /etc/mail/mailfilter
```

... I get following error:

```
preline: usage: preline cmd [ arg ... ]
```

Just to mention that upper line is content of the file

```
/home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/.qmail-default
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong with this, and how to use preline command in this case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your `.qmail*` file should have a pipe character at the beginning of the line, which you didn't show here, but it looks like `preline` is being run, so that's probably not the actual problem. Still it would be nice to see the real unaltered `.qmail-default`. If the problem isn't there, we'll need to know some of the surrounding context. Is `/home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com` the home directory of some user? Presumably with a `virtualdomains` mapping?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add pipe in my primary post, and .qmail-default looks like in my primary post

Comment: directory /home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com is not home dir of some user

Comment: A good way to debug such problems is to attach an `strace -ff -s200 -o /tmp/qmail.log` to the `qmail-lspawn` process, then attempt a delivery. The strace log should show you how preline is actually called or how it fails (maybe the error message is misleading).

Comment: @AndrásKorn Could you provide more details on this process attach? How to deatach once the debugging is finished?

Comment: @Danijel, just press CTRL-C to stop strace (and thus deattach it from the process it is tracing). You can give strace the PID of the qmail-lspawn process to attach to using the -p switch; see man strace.

Answer (score 2):

This happend to me after uprgading/recompiling qmail
The fix is, recompile vpopmail ;)